# Finding a integer number after a beginning t=

Tags: regex, grep

I have a string like this:

```
33 00 4b 46 ff ff 03 10 30 t=25562
```

I am only interested in the five digits at the very end after the *t=*

How can I get this numbers with a regular expression out of it?
I tried `grep t=.....` but I also got all characters including the *t=* in the beginning, which I would like to drop?

After finding that five digit number, I would like to divide this by `1000`. So in the above mentioned case the number `25.562`. Is this possible with grep and regular expressions?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
echo '33 00 4b 46 ff ff 03 10 30 t=25562' | awk -F= '{print $2/1000}'
```

Output:

```
25.562
```

---

**EDIT**

As pointed out by *@anubhava* in comment, above assumes `=` is not present anywhere before `t=`. If that's not the case,

```
echo '33 00 4b 46 ff ff 03 10 30 t=25562' | awk -F' t=' '{print $2/1000}'
```

Comment: This assumes `=` is not present anywhere before `t=`

Comment: @anubhava that's true and is applicable for provided example. If not following modification seems obvious `-F"t="`. Updated my ans. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I don't nitpick but `t=` is pretty risky field separator I believe. At least make it `-F ' t='`

Comment: Great, now I can delete my answer and +1 yours

Comment: @anubhava I've to fight really hard to write a sensible ans where you jump in! Everywhere else you steal the show :) Appreciate your answers. You can keep yours for reference of `grep -oP` with `\K`. I had learnt that from your previous ans only...

Comment: It seems OP is after arithmetic calculation not just capture that's why I deleted since your awk command is simpler :P

Answer (score 0):

This should be OK.  It will only get value form `t=` at the end. OP also post that `t=` could exist as extra character in the middle of the line, but hi only like to get the one at the end of the line.

```
echo '33 00 4b 46 ff ff t=22 03 10 30 t=25562' | awk '{split($NF,a,"=");print a[2]/1000}'
25.562
```

---

Another variation

```
echo '33 00 4b 46 ff ff t=22 03 10 30 t=25562' | awk 'END {print $0/1000}' RS==
25.562
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This and the above answer work for me. Best thanks.